# Refacto, algo/logic issues

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm the head in the refacto of my code because it's a mess.
But since I'm on it from yesterday, my head look like a stone -_-"

```
    #region DateTime foreach Currencies
    static DateTime eurusd = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurgbp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurjpy = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime usdjpy = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpjpy = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpusd = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);


    static DateTime eurusdm1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurgbpm1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurjpym1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime usdjpym1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpjpym1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpusdm1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

    static DateTime eurusdh1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurgbph1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurjpyh1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime usdjpyh1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpjpyh1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpusdh1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

    static DateTime eurusdd1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurgbpd1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime eurjpyd1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime usdjpyd1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpjpyd1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    static DateTime gbpusdd1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    #endregion
```

There are 24 different DateTime.

```
            switch (data.Instrument)
            {

                case "EUR/USD":
                    if (CanUpdate(ref eurusd, "s5"))
                    { InsertData("eurusd", data); }
                    if (CanUpdate(ref eurusdm1, "m1"))
                    { InsertData("eurusdm1", data);}
                    if (CanUpdate(ref eurusdh1, "h1"))
                    { InsertData("eurusdh1", data);}
                    if (CanUpdate(ref eurusdd1, "d1"))
                    { InsertData("eurusdd1", data);} 
            }
```

A switch case with 6 Case (like the one above)
(InsertData just put some object in a collection. "x" => collection name, data => the object)

```
    private bool CanUpdate(ref DateTime date, string timer)
    {
        TimeSpan result = DateTime.Now - date;

        if (timer == "s5")
        {
            int difSeconds = result.Seconds;
            if (difSeconds >= 5)
            {
                date = DateTime.Now;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (timer == "m1")
        {
            int difMinutes = result.Minutes;
            if (difMinutes >= 1)
            {
                date = DateTime.Now;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (timer == "h1")
        {
            int difHour = result.Hours;
            if (difHour >= 1)
            {
                date = DateTime.Now;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (timer == "d1")
        {
            int difDays = result.Days;
            if (difDays >= 1)
            {
                date = DateTime.Now;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My "CanUpdate" Method. Check the time between the last update and if the "if condition" are true it update the "date variable" and return true, else it return false.

As you can guess, this switchcase have more or less 70 lines. One change need to be repercuted on the whole switchcase. Ugly right ?

I would like to get rid of this switchcase and make it more maintainable.
I've think about put all of the data in different list.
So it will look like:

```
    List<String> collectionName;
    List<DateTime> dateTime;
    List<String> timeFrame;
```

and do a foreach on the DateTime collection then do 2 nested for.
Somthing like:

```
foreach (DateTime dt in dateTime)
{
    for(i=0; i <= collectionName.Lenght; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j <= timeFrame.Lenght; j++)
        {
            CanUpdate(ref dt, timeFrame[j])
            InsertData(collectionName[i].ToString(), data)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I in the right direction and do you even understand what I would like. Because if your head are in the same state as mine after reading this. Sorry :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preamble

1. I would (and, in fact, I did) use Dictionary to solve this problem.
2. I'm not a big fan of Tuple. So, for real application I would create some struct/class instead.
3. For the answer I assume that it's required to work with strings of formats "EUR/USD" and "eurusdm1" (see method `GetInsertDataArgument()`).
4. Of course, I haven't tested the code :) But I think it's more than enough to get the idea.
5. I've decided to make all the members static because you had your datetimes static in the original code. You can easily change this.

## Code

```
class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, DateTime> lastUpdateDateTimes = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, DateTime>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, TimeSpan> timeIntervals = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();

    static MyClass()
    {
        timeIntervals.Add("s5", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        timeIntervals.Add("m1", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        timeIntervals.Add("h1", TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        timeIntervals.Add("d1", TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    }

    private static string GetInsertDataArgument(string instrument, string timeIntervalName)
    {
        string result = instrument.Replace("/", "").ToLower();
        if (timeIntervalName != "s5")
            result = result + timeIntervalName;
        return result;
    }

    private static void Update(string instrument)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var timeInterval in timeIntervals)
        {
            var dateTimeKey = new Tuple<string, string>(instrument, timeInterval.Key);
            if (now - lastUpdateDateTimes[dateTimeKey] < timeInterval.Value)
                continue;
            lastUpdateDateTimes[dateTimeKey] = now;
            InsertData(GetInsertDataArgument(instrument, timeInterval.Key), data);
        }
    }
}
```

## What's going on

There are 2 dictionaries:

1. `lastUpdateDateTimes` stores datetimes for each currency pair and time interval. First member of tuple stores currency pair (in "EUR/USD" format), second member stores time interval name (in "s5" format).
2. `timeIntervals` holds your time intervals. It is filled in static constructor of class.

`Update` method is the replacement for your switch statement and CanUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you. Your idea are really good.
exactly what I needed especially the:

```
     Dictionnary<Tuple<string,string>,DateTime>
```

I was wondering how to make all those data relational.

I just needed to delete the

```
     if (timeIntervalName != "s5")
```

because
   "result = result + timeIntervalName;"

should be trigger every time GetArgumentName are called.

Neded to make a

```
    TimeSpan timeElapsed = now - lastUpdateDateTimes[dateTimeKey];
```

Because it didn't work in the condition even between (). Don't know why, it should.(?)

And I also needed to populate my lastUpdateDateTimes Dictionnary. (ofc)

So, thank you again. Work like a charm.